# API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG: API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner

Tags: api, professional-edition

How to enable the API for PE salesforce ? currently I am getting error like "API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG: API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner" but I can see the some calls are used [image: See below image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can add API access to Professional Edition for an additional fee. Talk to your Account Exec.

Answer (score 2):

Some managed packages can utilize the API in Professional Edition orgs as described here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_api_access.htm

Comment: Currently I have 51 Salesforce license out of 52 and I have already installed managed package from AppExchange. Please advise.

Comment: Not true that you have to upgrade, but you're correct on the managed packages. I'll edit out the first paragraph of your answer - hope that's ok. Really edits are supposed to be for spelling and formatting, not content, but this seems friendlier than a downvote.

Comment: Thanks. Last PE org I worked with the Account Exec told them in order to get API access the "Had" to upgrade to a different edition. That has been a year ago. Glad you can now get it for a fee.